# How to copy nodes from an existing div into another div Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

Im not sure what im doing wrong, but iv created 5 images placed at random positions in the left div and i want to copy all 5 - the firstchild and place them on the right side. So il have 5 images on the left and 4 on the right. I debugged my if with alert and it does run, but i cant figure out what wrong with my code? Why is it not print images to the right hand side? Any help is appreciated thank you

```js
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftside");
var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightside");
facesNeeded = 5;
totalfFaces = 0;

function makeFaces() {
 while(facesNeeded != totalfFaces) {  
  smiley = document.createElement("img");
  smiley.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
  smiley.style.top = Math.random() * 401 + "px";
  smiley.style.left = Math.random() * 401 + "px"; 
  document.getElementById("leftside").appendChild(smiley);
  totalfFaces++;
  // alert(totalfFaces); used to debug
 } 
 if (facesNeeded == totalfFaces){
  alert("hi");
  leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
  leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.childNode[0]);
  document.getElementById("rightside").appendChild(leftSideImages);
        //alert("hi");
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
  img{
   position: absolute;
  }
  div {
   position: absolute;
   width:500px;
   height:500px;
  }
  #rightside { 
  left: 500px; 
    border-left: 1px solid black;
   }
  </style>
  <script src="script3.js"></script>      
  </head>
  <body onload="makeFaces()"> 
   <h1> Matching Game</h1>
   <p> Click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>       
      <div id="leftside"></div>
      <div id="rightside"></div>     
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in this line:

```
leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.childNode[0]);
```

it should be:

```
leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.childNodes[0]);
```

---

Full code:

```js
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftside");
var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightside");
facesNeeded = 5;
totalfFaces = 0;

function makeFaces() {
 while(facesNeeded != totalfFaces) {  
  smiley = document.createElement("img");
  smiley.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
  smiley.style.top = Math.random() * 401 + "px";
  smiley.style.left = Math.random() * 401 + "px"; 
  document.getElementById("leftside").appendChild(smiley);
  totalfFaces++;
  // alert(totalfFaces); used to debug
 } 
 if (facesNeeded == totalfFaces){
  alert("hi");
  leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
  leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.childNodes[0]);
  document.getElementById("rightside").appendChild(leftSideImages);
        //alert("hi");
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
  img{
   position: absolute;
  }
  div {
   position: absolute;
   width:500px;
   height:500px;
  }
  #rightside { 
  left: 500px; 
    border-left: 1px solid black;
   }
  </style>
  <script src="script3.js"></script>      
  </head>
  <body onload="makeFaces()"> 
   <h1> Matching Game</h1>
   <p> Click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>       
      <div id="leftside"></div>
      <div id="rightside"></div>     
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the code works when i run it with stack overflows run code snippet option, but doesnt work when i run it in my own browser?

Comment: You're welcome. I've only changed that typo, so if you original code worked, so should the new one.

Comment: When i run the code snippet on stack it works and i see 5 and 4 images, when i save and open it as a HTML it only shows the left side with images, same problem as my first post :/

Comment: Then you have something extra in your code... or you didn't copy everything.

Comment: Im just copying the code, no extra. Not sure why it works here and not in my browser when i load my own html. Thanks though

Comment: script3.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of null

Comment: Seems like you're calling the script function before the DOM is ready. Are you sure you're using window onload?

Comment: i called it from the body tag, like <body onload="makeFaces()">, is that wrong?

Comment: That's fine. The thing is that this `var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftside");` returns null, as if it cannot find the div. Are you sure the variable names are the same and correct?

Comment: Of course!!! You initialize the variables from script3.js, and at that time the DOM is not ready (the divs don't exist). You can initialize the var from inside the function (like this: http://jsfiddle.net/u060ukkk/) or load the script at the end of the body and execute it right away (by calling the function). Sorry I missed that.

Comment: that works and makes sense thank you! Though how would i load and then call at the end of the body as i want to keep those variables global?

Comment: You're welcome. To keep them global, you can use what you have, just don't use `var` when declaring them. To load at the end of the body, just move your script tag there, call the function from inside the script and remove the body onload.

Comment: do i use window.onload to call it within the script tag?

Comment: No, just `makeFaces()` is fine.

Comment: that doesnt appear to be working for me, thank you for all your help though

Comment: How come? You should always explain how something is not working and include any errors it shows.

Comment: http://puu.sh/ltFQy/d2e1272ccc.png
Theres no error in console, it just doesnt display images

Comment: I see, I meant to put `makeFaces()` inside the script itself, not inside the script tags.

Comment: Thank you so much dude. Muchos appreciated

Comment: No problem, mate, glad I could help. :)